# Searching for framework for my application

Tags: c++, windows, frameworks, cross-platform

I am searching for a framework(preferably c++, but i can learn other languages too) for my application. I will write what i need:

Borderless window(no buttons,frames etc.)
Real time 3d model rendering(or at least easy way to show 2d animation made from 3d model)
Cross-platform support(not mandatory)

If there is any other details you need to know, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best cross-platform Gui-Frameworks for C++ is Qt. It can do 3d-stuff using OpenGL too. However, if you only need a plain window without any controls you may want to look into the next OpenGL tutorial for some infos.

Comment: Can ir render 3d model with animations directly or do i need to make 2d animation first?

Comment: Yes you can do 3d animations directly. But you need to know OpenGL for that. You can use OpenGL without Qt though. There are some leightweight OpenGL gui libraries out there. I would recommend you to start with OpenGL first, because Qt is quite heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

Xojo will also do what you want. It creates Windows, OS X and Linux desktop apps and has built-in support for OpenGL.

http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

It works in Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, and Android. (Furthermore in some game consoles.)

Its support languages are C#, boo and js.
C# is like C++ and easy to learn.